# VIM: can't fully understand this substitution

Tags: vim, vi

I have taken this line of code from a book to format html code into a string-concatenated form for use in javascript in vim. I can't seem to understand what the numbers '1' and '2 represent and what the question marks are for at the end of the regexes. I'm used to seeing substitutions like **%s/foo/bar/g**, so the absence of forward slashes confuses me a bit. Summarized, I don't understand the '**1**' and '**2**', the question marks after the dollar sign and before the carriage return, and why the forward slashes are not used.

```
vmap <silent> ;q :s?^\(\s*\)\(.*\)\s*$? \1 + '\2'?<CR>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said in other answers, the `/` delimiter can be replaced by some other char : when many slashes are used in the command, it may be more clear; see a question about it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568901/3271687.

`\1`, `\2`, `\n...` match the *n*th sub-expression used in the pattern. A sub-expression is defined with `\(` and `\)`. So in your example:

```
:s?^\(\s*\)\(.*\)\s*$? \1 + '\2'?
                 \s*   -->  note that this part can't be reached, it's useless
```

, `\1` is replaced by the spaces found in `\(\s*\)`, and `\2` is replaced by all the chars (the whole rest of the line) found in `\(.*\)`.

Answer (score 1):

Forward slashes are typically used as the separator, but the substitute command uses the first character after the 's' as the separator, allowing it to be changed to anything. It seems the author thought that all the slashes might be confusing, so changed it to a '?'. This is how the command would appear with the more traditional forward slashes:

```
:s/^\(\s*\)\(.*\)\s*$/ \1 + '\2'/<CR>
```

So the above would mean, search forward, finding lines starting with any amount of whitespace, followed by any number of any characters, and any amount of whitespace, and then substitute it for `<space><the first whitespace><space>+<space>'<the other characters>'`.  I think it was intending to strip any trailing whitespace, but in my testing it doesn't do that, because the .* will match everything to the end of the line.

Comment: Actually, I tested and '?' doesn't search backwards in a substitute command. It is simply using a different character as the separator. Updating...

Comment: Thanks. What do the \1 and \2 do?

Comment: @DarkNawg The characters between the \( and \) form a group, and whatever matches that expression can then be used later in the replacement string. \1 and \2 are used to indicate that the the first and second groups. So in the first group we have whatever matched \s* (any amount of whitespace) and in the second we have whatever matched .* (any amount of any character). See here for more deets: http://vimregex.com/#backreferences