# what do the + signs mean in vimscript regex strings

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

You can find this syntax being commonly used in syntax vimscripts. For example you can  find it in the file `<vimdir>\syntax\python.vim` on line 113 in vim 7.4 (win7):

```
syn match pythonEscape +\\[abfnrtv'"\\]+ contained
```

My simple question is what do the `+` signs mean at the either end of the regex string literal?

I could not find anything with `:help literal-string` and `:help regex` or steve losh's [book](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/). Where do you think I should have been looking?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what about the `+` at the beginning of the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there's no atom before that

Comment: they appear to be marking the beginning and end of the literal like `'` or `"` or `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are indeed the start and end of the regex, in vim you can use any character as a delimiter.  I remember reading this in Drew Neil's book "Practical Vim", but I also found an example here:  http://www.hacktux.com/vi/replace

> **Escaping Characters**
>
> You will have to escape out the slash  if it is part of your search string:
>
> `%s/http:\/\//https:\/\//g`
>
> **Use Any Delimiter**
>
> Alternatively, change your delimiter. It can be anything!
>
> `%s!http://!https://!g`

From [sidyll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557306/sidyll) in the comments:

> Just for the sake of completeness, you may want to add the official help reference: `:h E146`. This is explained in the flags section, one of the last paragraphs at `:h s_flags`

Comment: yes! delimiter was the word i should have been using in search! Hence, I also found [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_delimiters_for_the_replace_command)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, you may want to add the official help reference: `:h E146`. This is explained in the flags section, one of the last paragraphs at `:h s_flags`.